# How to compute distance between movable items in the screen?

Tags: image-processing, distance

I want to design a box in which I can move a set of items. Specifically, there should be N items (e.g. little balls with numbers inside).
Items can be arranged with the mouse inside a box, and, in real time, I want the program that computes a matrix with the distance between every pair of objects and its eigenvectors. I want the distance matrix to have the items as image-labels in each axis.
I would really appreciate some help here, I have been using Mathematica for statistical analysis, but never for graphical processing.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the very generous help of J. M. , I found a way to do exactly what I wanted. Here is the code.

```
n = 10; (*Number of objects*)

DynamicModule[{pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]}, 
Row[{Panel[
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Framed@Graphics[{}], 
 Appearance -> Flatten[Table[{"" <> ToString[i]}, {i, n}]]]], 
Dynamic[Panel[NumberForm[
  MatrixForm /@ With[{d = Outer[EuclideanDistance, pt, pt, 1]},
    {MatrixPlot[d, PlotLabel -> "Distances"], 
     MatrixPlot[Eigenvectors[d], 
      PlotLabel -> "Eigenvectors (Sorted)"], 
     Abs[Eigenvalues[d]]}], 4]]]}, Spacer[12]]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know where to start, I'd recommend looking at [LocatorPane](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html).

Comment: I looked at this post and I am trying to do something similar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299569/move-objects-with-the-mouse-using-manipulate-in-mathematica. They use Manipulate[]

Comment: It depends on what kind of UI you want. If you want to drag the pictures around then it's easiest to use `LocatorPane`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}]}, 
              Row[{Panel[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
                                     Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 1], 
                                     Appearance -> "\[EmptyCircle]"]], 
                   Dynamic[Panel[
                   NumberForm[Column[MatrixForm /@ 
                   With[{d = DistanceMatrix[pt]}, {d, Eigenvectors[d]}]], 4]]]},
                  Spacer[12]]]
```

[image: movable points and their distance matrix]

---

Here is a slight modification of the OP's version:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}]}, 
              Row[{Panel[LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
                                     Framed[Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 1]], 
                                     Appearance -> Array[IntegerString, Length[pt]],
                                     LocatorAutoCreate -> True]], 
                   Dynamic[Panel[
                           With[{d = DistanceMatrix[pt]}, 
                                Grid[{{MatrixPlot[d, PlotLabel -> "Distances"], 
                                       MatrixPlot[Eigenvectors[d],
                                                  PlotLabel -> "Eigenvectors (Sorted)"]},
                                      {NumberForm[Abs[Eigenvalues[d]], 4],
                                       SpanFromLeft}}]]]]}, Spacer[12]]]
```

[image: new version]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is super helpful.

Comment: I posted my final code, just in case you want to see it :) Thank you again!

Comment: I modified your code a bit; hopefully it's an improvement.